# what does "invalid_grant" error with "inactive user" description mean?

Tags: error, oauth

The title is pretty much the whole question, I have seen the "invalid_grant" error in the Oauth2 flow alot of times and the description is always "expired access/refresh token" just like the webpage https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&language=en

I have seen another 2 webpages that have the "invalid_grant" error code but they don't have the new error description I got:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US , https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US

But recently I got the same error code but with a different description "inactive user", I tried making an account and set it to "inactive" from its administrator account but I didn't get that error.

Does anyone know what can that error result from?